# How can I implement the simple text statistics report in jbehave BDD framework?

Tags: java, statistics, jbehave, serenity-bdd, extentreports

I am using the Jbehave framework and I am also using the Extent Report. But after all the stories executed I want just statistics report like How many Stories Run, How many PASSED, How many FAILED, How many steps executed,etc.. in just TEXT format.
How can I get this?

Currently my Configuration function is:

```
@Override
public Configuration configuration() {
    LOG.info(" setting report configuration ");
    Class<? extends Embeddable> embeddableClass = this.getClass();
    Properties viewResources = new Properties();
    viewResources.put("decorateNonHtml", "true");
    return new MostUsefulConfiguration()
            .useStepMonitor(new PrintStreamStepMonitor())
            .doDryRun(false)// default is "false"
            .useStoryLoader(new LoadFromClasspath(this.getClass()))
            .useStoryReporterBuilder(new AlogysStoryReporterBuilder().withCrossReference(xref))
            .useStepPatternParser(new RegexPrefixCapturingPatternParser())
            .useStepMonitor(xref.getStepMonitor())`enter code here`;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried embedded reporters: https://jbehave.org/reference/stable/reporting-stories.html ?

Comment: I'm curious why you included a tag to extent reports since you show no code implementing extent reports.